# Laravel and Wordpress Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5

I am building a web app on Laravel, which involves logins by multiple user types etc.

I would like to use Wordpress backend and frontend for most the CMS related stuff. I want to Wordpress frontend, as it is easier to maintain for the client, and a lot of the site's user facing pages are content that can be from wordpress.

I want the site to show pages from wordpress, *if* the route is not being handled by Laravel.

http://webapp.com/ -> (Landing Page)from Wordpress

http://webapp.com/laravelRoute -> Laravel

http://webapp.com/some-post-url -> Wordpress.

How can I achieve this by letting Laravel and Wordpress play nice with routing?

I've tried installing Wordpress in public/ folder. However it doesn't recognise Laravel routes, works like a general wordpress site.

Comment: `But it is not working` is your error?

Comment: Will share an error in a minute.

Comment: @IvascuMadalin Installing in public folder showing just the wordpress site. I tried adding the index.php code from Laravel's public/index.php on top. It shows just the laravel routes then.

Comment: **I tried adding the index.php code from Laravel's public/index.php on top** on top of what ?

Comment: @IvascuMadalin on top of the existing code. `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`. Why so aggressive?

Comment: sory,why did you do that? you can keep both your application separated

Comment: Just trying if it works. What would the best way you suggest? 
I am trying to see if there I can redirect page handling to wordpress depending on routes. 

`
Route::get('/',function(){

// Let wordpress handle the code generation.
});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156979/discussion-between-santosh-achari-and-ivascu-madalin).

Comment: @IvascuMadalin Thank you for the chat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I was able to fix it.

http://example.com/ -> Laravel code

`<laravel code root>/public/pages` -> wordpress code

You should be able to access `http://example.com/pages/` -> from the wordpress content.

You also need to configure nginx to handle Wordpress URL redirects:

```
        ...
        location /pages/index.php(/.*)?$ {        
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/pages/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location /pages/ { 
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^.*$ /pages/index.php last;    
                }
            try_files $uri $uri/ pages/index.php?args; 
        }
        location / { ...
```

Comment: How can we achieve this on apache server?

Answer (score 2):

To merge both Laravel and Wordpress on the same level you have two options or maybe more.

The first option is to setup .htaccess rewrite rules and redirect all Laravel routes to a laravel-index.php file. You rename the Laravel app index.php file to that.

The second option is to disable the wordpress index.php file and instead use Laravel's. In laravel create a catch all route that call the Wordpress object. So with this method, all you have to do is create the Laravel routes and the rest will just fall through to Wordpress.

Comment: The @scriptonomy. 

Can you share more how the code would like for the second option?

Comment: I've tried doing something like:  ```Route::get('/',function(){ // Let wordpress handle the code generation. }); ```